# Leaflet: How to style 2000+ points in a GeoJSON object with no style properties?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a single GeoJSON FeatureCollection object that contains over 2000 features. In the GeoJSON object, each feature is part of one category like so:

```
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "category": "Electrical",
    "Name": "Plane No 2"
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      94.5703125,
      58.722598828043374
    ]
  }
},
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "category": "Military",
    "Name": "Base 1"
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      104.4140625,
      62.91523303947614
    ]
  }
},
```

In my actual data, there are a total of about 38 categories (each feature is only assigned to one category).

Is using a JavaScript Switch Statement in my situation a practical solution in order to give each point its own styling? Or, is there a better way?

I am doing something like this in my code:

```
L.geoJson(mygeoJson, {
onEachFeature: function (feature, layer){
    layer.bindPopup(L.Util.template(popupTemplate, feature.properties));
},
pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng){
    return L.circleMarker(latlng, gjsonOptions);
},
// 3 of the 38 categories are listed here as an example
style: function(feature){
        switch(feature.properties.category){
            case 'Electrical': return { color: '#fb8072'};
            case 'Military': return { color: '#b3de69'};
            case 'Aviation': return { color: '#80b1d3'};
        }
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

[**Demo link here**](http://ogmda.com/sandbox/map.html)

Comment: There's probably a few different ways to do this. Is there a way you could modify the GeoJSON to add a new property (which would just be the hex color)? If not, you could always store these as objects in an array and use another library (like undersore or lodash) to do the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: If you know what shapefiles are, I'm actually taking shapefiles and then converting it to the GeoJSON format. I suppose I have those shapefiles edited to so they have a new field with hexcolors.

Comment: That would be my recommendation. Then you don't need any other libraries, etc. if you get stuck or something just comment back on this thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think one should add the colors on the clientside, just as he/she did in the code example. adding the colors to each GeoJSON feature will needlessly bloat your transfer. If you really want to add them to your collection you could create some sort of legend property in your collection object like so:

```
var collection = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "properties": {
        "legend": {
            "Electrical": "#fb8072",
            "Military": "#b3de69",
            "Aviation": "#80b1d3"
        }
    }
    "features": [...]
}
```

So that when you create your GeoJSON layer you can add them on the fly:

```
L.geoJson(collection, {
    'style': function (feature) {
        return {
            'color': collection.properties.legend[feature.properties.category]
        }
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

You could instead of storing the legend in the collection object, store it in your code/script somewhere:

```
var legend = {
    "Electrical": "#fb8072",
    "Military": "#b3de69",
    "Aviation": "#80b1d3"
}

L.geoJson(collection, {
    'style': function (feature) {
        return {
            'color': legend[feature.properties.category]
        }
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

Edit after comments:

If you need to set L.Marker icons you should use the pointToLayer function:

```
L.geoJson(collection, {
    'pointToLayer': function (feature, latlng) {
        return new L.Marker(latlng, {
            'icon': new L.Icon({
                'iconUrl': 'icons/' + feature.properties.category + '.png'
                ...
            })
        })
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

You're currently using L.CircleMarker which doesn't support the icon option. It's a path which only supports the pathoptions:

- http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#path-options

Here's a nice tutorial on creating L.Marker's with custom icons:

- http://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons.html

Comment: I fully agree with that. If your data already has categories that you can rely on to do your styling, you'd better not overcharge your data. There is nothing wrong with the switch method. Then you can even let your user change the styling of each category on client side!

Comment: Good points. Would I also be able to set image icons for each category using the style property or do I need to invoke some other method?

Comment: Thank you. I decided to go with your second example (loading the colors in  the variable legend) since I'd prefer not to deal with touching the data collection itself.